# Use ListView and TreeView to list folders and files

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a windows form that contains two controls (TreeView and ListView), i want to display all directories for a specific path in the `TreeView` and when the user clicks to any directory listed in the `TreeView` all the files of this directory shown in the `ListView`.

That is my code:

In Form_Load event handler i loaded all the directory from E Drive to the treeView1

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"E:\");
        foreach (DirectoryInfo d in dInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(d.Name);
        }

    }
```

Here is the problem:

```
        private void treeView1_AfterSelect(object sender, TreeViewEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo(e.Node.Text);
            foreach (FileInfo f in dInfo.GetFiles())
            {
                listView1.Items.Add(f.Name);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, ex.Source);
        }

    }
```

When any body click on any directory in the treeView1 the code jump to the catch insted of listing all files in the listView1.

The Exception Message: Couldn't find a part of the path.

Comment: The problem is that you're adding `d.Name` to the treeview node rather than `d.FullName`. So when you create the new `DirectoryInfo`, it doesn't have the full path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add some data to the tree node. You can either put the full path name in the `Text`, by changing your code to:

```
treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(d.FullName);
```

Or, you can use the `Name`, and add some extra data to the `Tag` field of the `TreeNode`.

```
var node = treeView1.Nodes[0].Nodes.Add(d.Name);
node.Tag = d;
```

Then, when you want the files for that directory, you write:

```
DirectoryInfo dInfo = (DirectoryInfo)e.Node.Tag;
foreach (FileInfo f in dInfo.GetFiles())
...
```

If you don't want to keep all of those `DirectoryInfo` references around, you can put the `FullName` in the `Tag` field:

```
node.Tag = d.FullName;
```

And then when you go to retrieve the files:

```
DirectoryInfo dInfo = new DirectoryInfo((string)e.Node.Tag);
```